Sitecore Internal Link coming with sitecore path in url in Multilingual site
I have a multilingual site with 2 languages, english and spanish.
For default language (english), internal link url's are fine but for spanish, internal links are coming as Sitecore Path instead of URLs.
How do I resolve this?

Can you please attach the site configuration in the answer as well. I believe you are not using SXA..

recently installed sxa after this the issue started .

which version of SXA you installed?

SXA version 11400

Is it possible to connect over Sitecore slack..Need to check some configuration...

are the links getting generated from the CD server or is there any computed field onto which links are getting generated from CM server?
